# How to block update to the postgresql database

Tags: postgresql

We have a production postgres database which is accessible by all team members.
We use pgadmin to administer the database.

For safety reasons, I am willing to make the database readonly. So that, only data can be viewed and cannot be modified
**(blocking any update operation to the database)**.

If any database update is required, then I can make the database to readwrite mode, make the modification
and change to readonly again.

There are **ROLES AND PRIVILEGES** options which can be used for achieving this functionality.

**But I am wondering if there is any Pgadmin UI options for making the database readonly.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The only way to do that safely is to revoke the privileges

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use Roles and Privileges ??

create multiple users

- master_user
- readonly_user
- etc

Once you have users created, you can grant access on database/ schema or even table level.
Share the readonly user with the team and keep the master user for admins / applications etc

More info on postgres roles and privileges: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/user-manag.html